# Getting deadlock on insert and select statement(sql server 2014) in java application

Tags: sql-server-2014, java

In my application there are many threads which uses insert and select statement to store/retrieve data from database.

I am getting deadlock in my production environment, I have observe deadlock from application log file.

[image]
I am not able to reproduce same situation on my development environment.

Please give me suggestion to:

- How to resolve this kind of deadlock?
- How to get more clear understanding to capture deadlock?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the deadlock graph? You can find it in the system health session. Instructions on how to retrieve it are (for instance) here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/01/09/sql-server-get-historical-deadlock-information-system-health-extended-events/

Comment: Deadlock is generated on Production environment and i don't have access to PRD environment database. I am trying to reproduce deadlock on my development environment.

Comment: Ask someone with sysadmin access to extract the deadlock graph for you.

Answer (score 1):

**How to resolve this kind of deadlock?**

As you have not provided your deadlock graph it will be impossible to give an answer about how to resolve the deadlock. Even with just deadlock graph sometime it is not possible to give a solution.  You might have to trace your calls and see the sequence of calls (involved in the deadlock), look at the execution plan, isolation level etc. Based on what you said (insert and select statement) I suggest you read this post which will give you a good start.

[SELECT/INSERT Deadlock](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29323/select-insert-deadlock)

**How to get more clear understanding to capture deadlock?**

As suggested by @spaghettidba in comment section you can look at the article mentioned there.

Few more articles for you:

- [Detecting and Ending Deadlocks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [SQL Server Deadlocks by Example](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/sql-server-deadlocks-by-example/)